# C# WPF click random button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, random, click

I have multiple buttons on WPF that perform Click method

```
 <Grid Margin="0,0,490,170">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="button00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="82" Margin="0,1,-114,-7" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button02" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="82" Margin="228,0,-342,-7" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="114" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button01" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="82" Margin="114,1,-228,-7" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114" Click="Button_Click" />
...
</Grid>
```

My on click is this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    methodDoingStuff(button);
}
```

and i have tried to automate that computer could randomly click on of buttons. 
Like this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x = rnd.Next(2);
int y = rnd.Next(2);
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "button" +(x.ToString() + y.ToString());
Button_Click(btn);
```

But i cant seem to able to do that.
Any tips how i can do that kind of thing?

Comment: See article https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/03/09/how-to-programmatically-click-a-button/

Comment: try to use FindName() to find by name
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Button btn = new Button(); is not any of you buttons.  It is just a button with a possible matching name.  There is no signature Button_Click(btn);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button[] allButtons = grid.Children.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
Random rnd = new Random();
int x = rnd.Next(0, allButtons.Length);
Button btn = allButtons[x];
btn.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```

...where "grid" is the `x:Name` of the `Grid` in your XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="0,0,490,170"> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
            int x = 0;
            int y = rnd.Next(2);
            var buttonName = "button" + (x.ToString() + y.ToString());
            var buttonControl = this.FindName(buttonName) as Button;
            if (buttonControl != null)
            {
                buttonControl.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, buttonControl));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an object list containing references to the buttons.

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button> {button00, button01, button02};
```

Then do something like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int selection = rnd.Next(0, 3);
buttonList[selection].RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```